# How to eliminate spurious warnings, re: JSON cache files, from conda when using new libmamba solver?

Tags: solver, conda-build, mamba

Since upgrading to the new `libmamba` solver, I'm getting these spurious warnings when I `conda build ...`:

```
warning  libmamba Could not parse state file: Could not load cache state: [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be string, but is null
warning  libmamba Could not remove state file "C:\\Users\\dbanas\\miniconda3\\pkgs\\cache\\c73d9827.state.json": The pro
```

And I'm wondering how to disable them.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using mamba 1.3.1. Yesterday i have ran `conda clean`. Can this have caused it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the directory for cache. it's C:\Users\dbanas\miniconda3\pkgs\cache\ for you.
the warning will disappear.